# Cant store facebook access token in android sqlLite3 database

Tags: android, sqlite, facebook-graph-api

I am making an application which involves facebook integration.
I have to store the access token so that it doesnt needs to login again to see the application. But i am not able to store the access token .
The following is the error which i get

```
08-16 13:57:53.236: ERROR/Database(7964): Error inserting acces_token=177852938929775|8e4aec98e182f7034b497766.3-618306968|YAriJqaRTDz1aIgNHjom_tdBnnw
08-16 13:57:53.236: ERROR/Database(7964): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: error code 19: constraint failed
08-16 13:57:53.236: ERROR/Database(7964):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.native_execute(Native Method)
08-16 13:57:53.236: ERROR/Database(7964):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.execute(SQLiteStatement.java:55)
08-16 13:57:53.236: ERROR/Database(7964):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1623)
08-16 13:57:53.236: ERROR/Database(7964):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1484)
08-16 13:57:53.236: ERROR/Database(7964):     at org.db.dbHelper.insertRows(dbHelper.java:63)
08-16 13:57:53.236: ERROR/Database(7964):     at org.neighbourhood.neighbourhood.onFacebookConnectorWorking(neighbourhood.java:142)
```

Code :-

```
  dbHelper db = new dbHelper(neighbourhood.this);
        db.open();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put("acces_token",   
                  facebookConnector.getFacebook().getAccessToken());
        db.insertRows(cv, "facebook");
        db.close();
```

Code to inset values in database :-

public class dbHelper {

```
private final String DATABASE_NAME = "neighbourhood.db";
private final String TAG = "dbHelper";

private static final String DATABASE_CREATE_TABLE_LOGIN = "create table login" +
        " (is_login text not null);";

private static final String DATABASE_CREATE_TABLE_FACEBOOK = "create table "
        + "facebook"
        + " (name text not null,"
        + "first_name text not null," +
        "last_name text not null," +
        "gender text not null," +
        "email text not null," +
        "id text not null," +
        "birthday text not null," +
        "acces_token text not null);";


private SQLiteDatabase myDatabase;
private myDbhelper helper;

public dbHelper(Context context) {
    helper = new myDbhelper(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
}

/**
 * This method is used to open the database in Writable mode
 * 
 * @return instance of the database
 */
public dbHelper open() {
    try {
        myDatabase = helper.getWritableDatabase();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    return this;
}

/**
 * This method is used for closing the database
 */
public void close() {
    myDatabase.close();
}


public long insertRows(ContentValues values, String tableName) {
    long val = myDatabase.insert(tableName, null, values);
    return val;
}

public Cursor getAllValues(String tableName) {
    Cursor myResult;
    myResult = myDatabase.query(tableName, null, null, null, null, null,
            null, null);

    return myResult;
}


private static class myDbhelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public myDbhelper(Context context, String name, CursorFactory factory,
            int version) {
        super(context, name, factory, version);
    }

    /**
     * this method is called when the database is created first time
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase _db) {
        _db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE_TABLE_LOGIN);
        _db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE_TABLE_FACEBOOK);

    }

    /**
     * this method is called when the database version is changed
     */
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase _db, int _oldVersion,
            int _newVersion) {
        /*
         * _db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS all_audio");
         * _db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS all_video");
         * _db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS all_playlist");
         */
        _db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS all_playlist_song");
        onCreate(_db);

    }
}
```

}

Comment: What does your database look like? And what is line 63 in dbHelper.java?

Comment: Your logcat error shows a constraint violation - could you add the code used to create the database table to your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your schema specifies that all fields of your `facebook` table should be `NOT NULL`, but you are only inserting the `acces_token` field which will force the remaining fields to be `NULL`.

```
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE_TABLE_FACEBOOK = "create table "
    + "facebook"
    + " (name text not null,"
    + "first_name text not null," +
    "last_name text not null," +
    "gender text not null," +
    "email text not null," +
    "id text not null," +
    "birthday text not null," +
    "acces_token text not null);";
```

This is why the exception says `android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: error code 19: constraint failed` - your `NOT NULL` constraints are being violated.

You need to either separate `acces_token` into a separate table (for instance, a hypothetical "admin" table), relax your constraints on the other fields, or insert an entire row of data instead of just the `acces_token`.

Answer (score 1):

The method insertRows should have the parameters as ContentValues.
And in that that method you have to call contentvalues.putall method to insert the values in the database.
Try this:

```
public long insertRows(ContentValues values, String tableName)
    {
        ContentValues in=new ContentValues();
        in.putAll(values);


        return myDatabase.insert(tableName, null, in);
    }
```

Comment: This is my insert rows method  ->                                              public long insertRows(ContentValues values, String tableName) {
  long val = myDatabase.insert(tableName, null, values);
  return val;
 }

Comment: shudnt it be in.putAll(values) ?? and isn't mine the same code?

Answer (score 0):

Till we see your table scheme, we can't provide information about what can cause an error. Maybe you limited **acces_token** length when create table?

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, there is no need to store the access token. There are some good reasons:

(1) Facebook API has a Singal-Sign-On feature that does exactly what you want

(2) The Access Token can change, this does not happen every day or every week, but it does, and when it does, you will need to update your database after a failed login.

(3) The API works with Android's official Facebook App, so if the user is logged on in the Facebook App on their phone, they won't have to in your App.

(4) If the user has not installed the official Facebook App on their phone, the cookie from the browser can be used, and this is automatically done via the Facebook API.